# Adding column values to one row

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a attendance sheet and i want to know how to combine all values of a column from a sql table to a single row and display it in the datagridview like this for example:

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Maybe showing what you have tried (the code) would help clarify your question. What values are you combining? Do you want some sort of total? Count?

Comment: I just want know if it is possible to show the data in the columns in just one row.Like if my query is SELECT remarks FROM `attendance`. I want to display all the result as rows in the datagridview.